# Dynamic Programming Implementation of Unique subset generation

Tags: algorithm, optimization, dynamic-programming

I came across this problem where we need to find the total number of ways in which you can form a subset of n(where n is the input by the user). The subset conditions are : the numbers in the subset should be distinct and the numbers in the subset should be in decreasing order.

Example: Given n =7 ,the output is 4 because the possible combinations are (6,1)(5,2)(4,3)(4,2,1). Note that though (4,1,1,1) also add upto 7,however it has repeating numbers. Hence it is not a valid subset.

I have solved this problem using the backtracking method which has exponential complexity. However, I am trying to figure out how can we solve this problem using Dynamic Prog ? The nearest I could come up with is the series : for n= 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 for which the output is 0,0,0,1,1,2,3,4,5,7,9 respectively. However, I am not able to come up with a general formula that I can use to calculate f(n) . While going through the internet I came across this kind of integer sequences in https://oeis.org/search?q=0%2C0%2C0%2C1%2C1%2C2%2C3%2C4%2C5%2C7%2C9%2C11%2C14&sort=&language=&go=Search  . But I am unable to understand the formula they have provided here. Any help would be appreciated. Any other insights that improves exponential complexity is also appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you call "unique subset generation" is better known as [integer partitions with distinct parts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)#Odd_parts_and_distinct_parts). Mathworld has an entry on [the Q function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PartitionFunctionQ.html), which counts the number of partitions with distinct parts.

**However**, your function does not count trivial partitions (i.e. `n -> (n)`), so what you're looking for is actually `Q(n) - 1`, which generates the [sequence that you linked in your question](https://oeis.org/A111133)--the number of partitions into *at least 2* distinct parts. [**This answer**](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1972048) to a similar question on Mathematics contains an efficient algorithm in Java for computing the sequence up to `n = 200`, which easily can be adapted for larger values.

---

Here's a combinatorial explanation of the referenced algorithm:

Let's start with a table of all the subsets of `{1, 2, 3}`, grouped by their sums:

```
 index (sum)    partitions        count
     0           ()                 1
     1           (1)                1 
     2           (2)                1
     3           (1+2), (3)         2
     4           (1+3)              1
     5           (2+3)              1
     6           (1+2+3)            1
```

Suppose we want to construct a new table of all of subsets of `{1, 2, 3, 4}`. Notice that every subset of `{1, 2, 3}` is also a subset of `{1, 2, 3, 4}`, so each subset above will appear in our new table. In fact, we can divide our new table into two equally sized categories: subsets which do *not* include `4`, and those that do. What we can do is start from the table above, copy it over, and then "extend" it with `4`. Here's the table for `{1, 2, 3, 4}`:

```
 index (sum)   partitions        count
     0          ()                 1
     1          (1)                1 
     2          (2)                1
     3          (1+2), (3)         2
     4          (1+3), [4]         2
     5          (2+3), [1+4]       2
     6          (1+2+3),[2+4]      2
     7          [1+2+4],[3+4]      2
     8          [1+3+4]            1
     9          [2+3+4]            1
    10          [1+2+3+4]          1
```

All the subsets that include `4` are surrounded by square brackets, and they are formed by adding `4` to exactly one of the old subsets which are surrounded by parentheses. We can repeat this process and build the table for `{1,2,..,5}`, `{1,2,..,6}`, etc.

But we don't actually needed to store the actual subsets/partitions, we just need the counts for each index/sum. For example, if with have the table for `{1, 2, 3}` with only counts, we can build the count-table for `{1, 2, 3, 4}` by taking each `(index, count)` pair from the old table, and adding `count` to the the current count for `index + 4`. The idea is that, say, if there are two subsets of `{1, 2, 3}` that sum to `3`, then adding `4` to each of those two subsets will make two new subsets for `7`.

With this in mind, here's a Python implementation of this process:

```
def c(n):
    counts = [1]

    for k in range(1, n + 1):
        new_counts = counts[:] + [0]*k

        for index, count in enumerate(counts):
            new_counts[index + k] += count

        counts = new_counts

    return counts
```

We start with the table for `{}`, which has just one subset--the empty set-- which sums to zero. Then we build the table for `{1}`, then for `{1, 2}`, ..., all the way up to `{1,2,..,n}`. Once we're done, we'll have counted every partition for `n`, since no partition of `n` can include integers larger than `n`.

Now, we can make 2 major optimizations to the code:

1. Limit the table to only include entries up to `n`, since that's all we're interested in. If `index + k` exceeds `n`, then we just ignore it. We can even preallocate space for the final table up front, rather than growing bigger tables on each iteration.
2. Instead of building a new table from scratch on each iteration, if we carefully iterate over the old table backwards, we can actually update it *in-place* without messing up any of the new values.

With these optimizations, you effectively have the same algorithm from [the Mathematics answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1972048) that was referenced earlier, which was motivated by generating functions. It runs in `O(n^2)` time and takes only `O(n)` space. Here's what it looks like in Python:

```
def c(n):
    counts = [1] + [0]*n

    for k in range(1, n + 1):
        for i in reversed(range(k, n + 1)):
            counts[i] += counts[i - k]

    return counts

def Q(n):
    "-> the number of subsets of {1,..,n} that sum to n."
    return c(n)[n]

def f(n):
    "-> the number of subsets of {1,..,n} of size >= 2 that sum to n."
    return Q(n) - 1
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I am having some difficulty in understanding the mathematics behind it though !

Comment: @user5566364 I agree, so I added an explanation (that doesn't involve generating functions) for the linked algorithm. It's kind of long, but I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help.